# Rewrite dynamic query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wampserver

The problem is I have page with player's wallpapers and when user click on a player name, he goes to the page:

```
player.php?name=Cristiano-Ronaldo
```

I get the name value by `$_REQUEST['name']` and I am trying to rewrite:

```
mysite.com/player.php?name=Cristiano-Ronaldo
```

to

```
mysite.com/Football-Players/Cristiano-Ronaldo
```

I have read and tried lot of suggestions on the net with no luck, the best thing I get to in my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)

RewriteRule   ^players/player\.php$ /Football-Players/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule   ^Football-Players/%1 /players/player.php?name=%1 [L]
```

But i still get 404 Not found Error.

I test this on wampserver on windows 7

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+players/player\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Football-Players/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Football-Players/([^/]+)/?$ /players/player.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you this work for me. I relay cat`t understand every parameter but i will try. Because of my newbie in programing i have in my sql table name parameter with space like "name=Roberto Carlosh". Can i mach spaces in query too?

Comment: Yes space will also be matches since space comes as `%20` to Apache.

Comment: can i replace %20 with "-" for example?

Comment: Can be done but that totally changes the nature of the question. Request you to mark this as accepted and post a new question so that it can be addressed better.

Comment: In the past you told me this code and how to use it. I just want to ask the meaning of 'Rewritebase /'. On redirecting page, most of elements disappear and i should change the link values for example for css file and more. Can i make it without 'Rewritebase /'?

Comment: Ok sure that can be eliminated. See my updated answer.

Comment: Need your help again @anubhava. I can`t understand why when i use your rules for one page like the above example everything is ok, but when i copy the rule and i use it for another page like **clubs.php?name=real madrid** i am redirect to player page.

Comment: Since this question is pretty old and as per norms of Stackoverflow it is not considered good for adding a new question via comment section I suggest you close this question by marking it as accepted and then open a new question linking this one to get the best answer of 2nd problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm have you enabled the `rewrite_module` in wampserver? You enable it via wampserver -> apache -> modules -> rewrite_module